# Float as integer binary conversion

Tags: algorithm, types, type-conversion

I have this problem regarding conversion:

I have an integer, but I know it represents a float. Here are some correspondence examples:

| Integer | Float |
| --- | --- |
| 16256 | 1.00 |
| 16262 | 1.05 |
| 16291 | 1.28 |
| 16298 | 1.33 |

My question is: what is the algorithm for this type of conversion? How can you get the float value if you read the bytes as integer with 32 bit?

I then want to write a function that returns the integer for that said float.

I'm not using any language. I'm using a cheat engine in a game and found out that 100 ingame translates to 16256, and so on by changing the values inside the game I get the values inside the cheat engine, I'm trying to write a converter to make my search easier.

Comment: Given enough samples you could work out a way to do it, but that's really the hard way to do it.  It's *much* easier if you know the binary format of your floats.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a 16-bit float representation with:

- 1 sign bit
- 8 exponent bits, with 127 bias
- 7 mantissa bits, with leading bit convention

It is known as the [bfloat16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format) floating point format.

If this is correct, then here is a basic implementation in JavaScript to translate the 16-bit integer to its intended interpretation:

```js
function asFloat(i) {
    let mantissa = i & 0x7F;
    let exponent = (i >> 7) & 0xFF;
    let negative = i >= 0x8000;
    
    // Remove exponent bias and add hidden bit to mantissa
    let result = (1.0 + mantissa / 128.0) * 2 ** (exponent - 127);
    return negative ? -result : result;
}

console.log(asFloat(16256));
console.log(asFloat(16298));
```

Note that for this "short" float, the above snippet prints too many digits, as really this 16-bit float format cannot represent that level of precision. 1.3333333 cannot be faithfully represented in a float data type, and the shorter the float format is, the less accurate it will be.

The inverse function could look like this:

```js
function asInt(f) {
    if (f < 0) return 0x8000 + asInt(-f);
    let exponent = Math.floor(Math.log2(f));
    let mantissa = Math.floor((f / 2**exponent - 1) * 128);
    return ((exponent + 127) << 7) + mantissa;
}

console.log(asInt(1));
console.log(asInt(1.33333));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, how did you found out the mantissa and the exponent?

Comment: The binary representation of 16256 has a sequence of 1111111 and then only 0. As it is quite common to have an exponent bias, and we got as info that this represented 1 (which has exponent 0), I assumed that these 1111111 represented the exponent bias (i.e. 127). There should not be other 1 bits, since it is common to hide the most significant 1-bit from the mantissa, and since the number 1 only has *that* one, all the binary 1 bits had to belong to the exponent.